# Boostrap-slider tooltip doesn't display properly on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

The [slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) works fine on my desktop but on mobile you need to press the circle (mover on the slider) several times for it to get focus and the tooltip to appear, otherwise you'd just be sliding blindly.

The slider HTML is:

```
<input name="sliderAvgT" id="sliderAvgT" type="text"><br />
```

Java:

```
sliderAvgT = new Slider("#sliderAvgT", { id: "slider12c", min: {{minAvgT}}, max: {{maxAvgT}}, range: true, value: [defaultMinAvgT, defaultMaxAvgT] });
```

CSS:

none

Comment: If you look through the Git Hub issues you will see there is an [open issue](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/issues/513) for the very thing you are asking for.

Comment: But is there an alternative hack-ish solution (like catching the slider on slide and printing the tooltip manually)?

Comment: Not sure. Someone may know a solution. A couple of workarounds would be to always show the tool-tip if you detect a mobile device (or if the screen size is small enough) You could also just display the text instead of using a tool-tip, [see example #6 here](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/)

Comment: Is it possible to set the tooltip to always on after the slider is created?

Comment: yes. Ill add it as an answer since there will be quit a bit of code to post

Answer (score 1):

Like we talked about in the comments this is currently a known and open issue on Git Hub. [You can read about it here](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/issues/513).

An alternate solution would be to always display the tooltip to the user so they can see the value when sliding on a mobile device. Using [example #8 taken from the demo site](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/):

```
// With JQuery
$("#ex8").slider({
    tooltip: 'always'
});

// Without JQuery
var slider = new Slider("#ex8", {
    tooltip: 'always'
});
```

Hope that helps.